# Automorphisms between two tuples of the same type

Tags: model-theory

Fix some first order structure in some fixed language. If tuple $b$ is the image of tuple $a$ under some automorphism, then they have the same type. Is the converse true? That is, for any fixed tuples $a$ and $b$ of the same type, is there an automorphism mapping $a\mapsto b$?

If so, do $a$ and $b$ need to satisfy the same first order formulas, or does it suffice to satisfy the same atomic formulas, or something like this?

---

**Edit**: The question as stated above is false (see below). I am now wondering whether the substructure generated by $a$ and the substructure generated by $b$ are isomorphic

Comment: Yes: the two structures are images of one another under an automorphism of a suitable superstructure.

Answer (score 5):

From *Model theory: An introduction* by David Marker, exercice 4.5.1:

> Let $\mathcal{M}=(X,<)$ be a dense linear order and $A= \{1- \frac{1}{n} \mid n  \geq 1 \} \cup \{2+ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \geq 1 \}$. Show that $1$ and $2$ realize the same type over $A$, but there is no automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ fixing $A$ pointwise sending $1$ to $2$.

And exercice 4.5.9:

> Let $x$ and $y$ be algebraically independent over $\mathbb{R}$. Order $\mathbb{R}(x,y)$ such that $x>r$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y>x^n$ for all $n>0$. Let $F$ be the real closure of $\mathbb{R}(x,y)$. Show that $\text{tp}^F(x)=\text{tp}^F(y)$, but there is no automorphism of $F$ sending $x$ to $y$.

Comment: OK, thanks! I am still wondering if anything like this should be true. For example, perhaps there is a homomorphism from a partial substructure generated by $a$ to a partial substructure generated by $b.

Comment: I don't know if it helps you, but if $a$ and $b$ have the same type then $a$ is sent to $b$ by an automorphism in an elementary extension.